# How to determine the difference between SQL Server dependencies on an aliased temp table vs persisted table

Tags: sql-server, dependencies, temp-tables, sql-server-2017

I am working on SQL Server 2017.

I am developing functionality that will detect and report on stored procedures references to non-existent tables (perhaps because the table was never properly created, was deleted, or was renamed without modifying the dependent code.

I ran into an issue however regarding aliased temp tables. I do not want to report on references to temp tables that do not exist (since they would only be created at run time anyway) It seems that in some cases in sys.sql_expression_dependencies a reference to a persisted table that doesn't exist, and a reference to an aliased temp table look identical.

I would expect that perhaps for the temp table the referenced_database_name would be temp_db or that there would be some other way to identify that the dependency is on a temp table so that I can suppress it from my results showing bad references.

The following code will create the problem that I am seeing with the dependency info. It creates two stored procedures, one updates an aliased non-existent persisted table, and the other creates a temp table, and updates it using an alias. Sys.sql_expression_dependencies shows dependencies on both aliased names, with no referenced_id value (indicating that it is referencing a non-existent object), and there seems to be no way to tell looking at the dependency which one may be a temp table.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE my_procedure
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE a_table
    SET a_table.some_column = 0
    FROM dbo.some_table a_table
    WHERE 1 = 0;
END;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE my_temp_procedure
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp_table
    (
        some_column INT
    );
    UPDATE a_temp_table
    SET a_temp_table.some_column = 0
    FROM #temp_table a_temp_table
    WHERE 1 = 0;
END;
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies;
```